# wxMediaCtrl->Create returns false after windows 10 update

Tags: media-player, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets 3.1.0, VS2013, Win10-Home

The following code used to work (bOK was true and I could further load&play a movie):

```
m_mediactrl = new wxMediaCtrl();
bool bOK = m_mediactrl->Create(this, wxID_MEDIACTRL, wxEmptyString, wxPoint(0, 0), size, 0, wxMEDIABACKEND_WMP10);
```

However, after Windows updated, the Create function returns false.
It happens the same with the Mediaplayer sample.
I tried the directshow backend, but same result.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: which OS did you have? Can you run Media Player in plain Windows and see if it starts?

Comment: It's working well on Win8 and also on Win10 (before the latest updates).

Comment: can you step into Create() and see what exactly fails? Also, did you try running Mediaq Player from the Windows itself?

Comment: I upgraded to Win10Ent and now Create and Load return True, but I don't get the Load event. Calling Play() also returns True, but I cannot see the video. WMP12 (the default installed version) plays it with no problems. Is wxWidgets not compatible with WMP10? What can I do in this case?

Comment: can you post some code?